# Chrome DevTools, Memory: what is `feedback_cell` and how to resolve memory leak that traces to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Testing memory leaks in Chrome DevTools (after several attach/detach the jQuery plugin) I have found that there are some delta objects but I can't understand their nature:

What is `feedback_cell` about which reports DevTools? I do not have such identifier in my code (here BsMultiSelect.js).

[image]
Line number points to method definition: `function staticContentGenerator(...) {` 
I guess the `feedback_cell` is something from internal js structures, but I can't find anything about it.

How to deal with such traces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the same question, but this article helped me to understand what is feedback_cell

https://rohitwhocodes.wordpress.com/2020/08/20/feedback-vectors-in-heap-snapshots/

TLDR;

- feedback_cell is not a cause of memory leak
- feedback_cell (also known as feedback vector) is array of metadata information maintained by v8 engine to optimize execution performance.

> **How do feedback vectors affect memory investigations?**
>
> They are a red herring and if you see a feedback_cell in the retainer
> list that you are investigating, you can safely assume this specific
> retainer list is not the cause of the leak.
>
> You can think of feedback vectors are soft references and hence it is
> safe to ignore them as a cause of a memory leak.

**Update**: as Sebastian said in comments

- If you think that you don't have a memory leak, but you still see these feedback_cells, this means you do have a memory, however it is not caused by these references

Comment: I think what's also important as a takeaway is this: If you *think* that you don't have a memory leak, but you still see these feedback_cells, this means you *do* have a memory, however it is not caused by these references.

Comment: should the second part of the sentence be as the following? "...you *do* have a memory **leak**, however..."
I mean, does that miss the word "leak"?